# How to fix the 'expected right parenthesis' happening in the 4th line : tau0*(t[j+1]-t[j]) in winbugs

Tags: parentheses, winbugs

I need to estimate four parameters using winbugs: `tau[i], mu1[i],mu2[i]and tau0[i]`.

When I click check the model, it shows `expected right parenthesis` between `tau0*` and `(t[j+1]-t[j])` in the 4th line. 
When I delete the `(t[j+1]-t[j])`, it shows the same `expected right parenthesis` between `c` and `<-(1-step( tau[i]-t[j]))`

```
model
{
#likelihood
   for(i in 1:n){   
    for(j in 1:m){      
 x[i,j]~ dnorm( mu[i,j],  tau0*(t[j+1]-t[j]))      
 mu[i,j]<- mu1*(t[j+1]-t[j])*a+mu1*(tau[i]-t[j])*b+mu2*(t[j+1]-tau[i])*b+mu2*(t[j+1]-t[j])*c       
 sigma <-1/sqrt(tau0)                                                                                       
 a<-step( tau[i]-t[ j+1] )
 b<-(step(tau[i]- t[j])-(step(tau[i]- t[j+1]))
 c<-(1-step( tau[i]-t[j]))
}
#prior
   tau[i]~dnorm(mutau,tautau)
   mutau~dorm(0,  0.001)
   tautau~dgamma(0.01, 0.01)
   sigmatau<-1/sqrt(tautau)
   mu1[i]~dnorm(mumu1, tau1)
   mumu1~dorm(0, 0.001)
   tau1~dgamma(0.01,0.01)
   sigmatau1<-1/sqrt(tau1)
   mu2[i]~dnorm(mumu2, tau2)
   mumu2~dorm(0, 0.001)
   tau2~dgamma(0.01,0.01)
   sigmatau2<-1/sqrt(tau2)

   tau0[i]~dgamma(alpha,beta)
   sigmatau0<-1/tau0
  }
}
DATA
list(n=5, m=16,   mutau=0, tautau=1,  mumu1=0, tau1=1,   mumu2=0, tau2=1, alpha=0.01, beta=0.01 )
```

I expected the right model syntax

Answer (score 0):

> b<-(step(tau[i]- t[j])-(step(tau[i]- t[j+1]))

```
(
    step(
            tau[i]- t[j]
        )
    -
    (
    step(
            tau[i]- t[j+1]
        )
    )
```

4 brackets opening, 3 brackets closing.
First bracket is not closed.

Comment: Thanks, that's a mistake. But winbugs reminded me of an error in  x[i,j]~ dnorm( mu[i,j],  tau0*(t[j+1]-t[j]))

Comment: @Yoghurt_Scarlett, dnorm takes variables as arguments, not expressions. Try declaring a tau variable as `tau0*(t[j+1]-t[j])` and then substituting it in the dnorm function.